# Discussion Forum - Deleting Posts

Tags: forum, discussion

Can non moderators delete their own posts?

I cant seem to delete my own posts when logged in as one of my member groups.

Is this normal or is there a member preference of sorts that i need to tweak?

Comment: EE version? And Balloonatic's answer should definitely work, unless you have an addon that is messing with your member group privileges.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, sorry. You have to tweak/create custom code/addon for it.

All possible permissions per forums/boards are handled via Forum Module CP :(
There is just can edit, and that's what my members has done, editing entries to have only a dot or few.

And if Im wrong for some very odd reason, It would be nice to know where that magic setting might be.

Comment: I guess if you are experiencing same problem the feature must not be available. Thanks

Comment: No, its not, sorry. I had a forum with over half of a million posts, and 10% of posts were dotted out due to lack of delete feature. Made me nuts. :)

Comment: These are the ones we can handle, nothing more out-of-the-box.
Can View Forum - Can View Hidden Forum - Can View Posts - Can Post Topic - Can Post Reply - Can Upload - Can Report - Can Search